# How to assign or return values to an array using the same name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

This is my javascript code:

```
var sampleArray = new Array();
var inx = 0;

if (!Array.prototype.setstring) {
    Array.prototype.setstring = function(index, columnid) {
        return this[index-1][columnid];
    }
}

var arr = new Array();
arr['a'] = "111";
arr['b'] = "222";
sampleArray.push(arr);
```

setting `sampleArray` and

```
var aaa = sampleArray.setstring(1, "a");
console.log(aaa); //111
```

I could see "111" coming out. And I want to add "333" values to "a".

```
sampleArray.setstring(1, "a") = "333";
```

At the heart of the matter, I want to use `.setstring(index, columnid)` to get a value and set a value. Is this possible? Is there any other way besides my code?

Comment: You can't do `sampleArray.setstring(1, "a") = "333";` as it will give you an "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" error.

Comment: yeah, I already know...  Is there any other way to use ".setstring(index, columnid)"? Or is there a way to return the array itself, not the array string value, when returning from the "setstring" function?

Comment: https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Comment: If you ask me why,
We use the "setstring" function on the existing system in " Active x ", which will change in new ways. However, I would like to replace the "setstring" function without modifying the existing logic as much as possible.